# How do I make a function argument as ReadOnly in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I understand that a struct/class member variable can be made ReadOnly (Unity), but can a variable passed to a function be made ReadOnly? Is it even necessary? Since not using "ref" would automatically mean it is a readonly variable rite? I couldn't find clear answers in google or Stack Overflow, but may be because it is simple and not complicated the way I am making it to be? Appreciate your answers. Thanks.

Here is my code within a class:

````
private void func1()
{
    var newList = new NativeList<int>(1024, Allocator.Temp);
    // write to newList
    func2(newList);
}

//need the read function to be burstable
[BurstCompile]
private static void func2([ReadOnly] NativeList<int> newList)
{
// do read operations on the newList
}```
````

Comment: in general for starters: `string` is not an unmanaged type (`int`, `bool`, `struct`, ....) so it can't be used as `T` in `NativeList<T>` anyway ...

Comment: And what you pass in is indeed a `struct NativeList<T>` **however** this only is a wrapper around a pointer into memory => You get a copy yes, but of the pointer, not of the memory => still points to the same memory

Comment: But finally if your `func2` literally has to `write to newList` .. then why should it be readonly at all?

Comment: Apologies for this. I am unable to add the exact code here, so editing the list to be a NativeList<int>. Ah, ok, since it is a wrapper around the pointer, how do I ensure ReadOnly for that NativeList? Is it even possible? The func2 does not write to the NativeList. It needs to be a static function with [BurstCompile]. Unable to change that aspect currently.

Answer (score 0):

> Since not using "ref" would automatically mean it is a readonly variable rite?

No. If using a value type like `int` or `DateTime` you would have a copy of the value, so further marking it `readonly` would serve no purpose: it's the method's copy, and nothing the method does will change the original. But with a reference type like `List<int>` you have a copy of the reference, so if you mutate the object, you are still referring to the same object and mutating the original.

In the the case of a List, you have a reference type and if you add, remove, or replace items, or change the properties of any of the list items, you have changed the original list.

One thing you can do is **change the argument type**. You can, for example, set the method to accept an `IEnumerable<int>` instead of a `List<int>`, and when you can do this *you can still pass a `List<int>` to the method*, because `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Then the only thing you will be able to do is iterate over the list. You won't be able to just call `.Add()` like normal, for example.

---

But there's a trick here... `NativeList<T>` is not `List<T>`, and a quick look at the docs shows it is in fact declared as a **`struct`** instead of a `class`. This makes it a value type, where you get a copy of the value when calling a method, instead of a reference to the object. And since you are further using a value type (`int`) for the items, you should be safe to pass this to a method knowing the method cannot change your original. If further seems `NativeList<T>` does **not** implement `IEnumerable<T>`, which is unfortunate but probably necessary for the efficacy of it's use case.

And then there's another trick here, and that is Unity. I am **not** a Unity developer, but another quick check at the documentation shows the type expects an allocator: that is, something telling how or where to allocate memory. It seems Unity may be doing something else for memory with this type, potentially making everything else I've said moot ‍♂️, where the object value is really just a pointer (and other state/metadata) for native memory. You'll want to review the docs carefully on what the actual behavior here will be. And in this situation, even `readonly` might not help, since that can only apply for **managed** memory. A type providing access outside the managed playground may do things the language keywords and platform attributes don't know how to enforce.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading .. as mentioned it is a `struct` which gets copied yes ... **but** within the struct there is mainly a **pointer** into native memory (thus the name `NativeList`) => when you copy it you do **not** copy the memory but only the pointer to the memory location => you very well might end up modifying the very same memory when writing to this NativeList .. which is the whole point of their existence see [Unity JobSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html) and in particular https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/job-system-copy-nativecontainer.html

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix/workaround. Using .AsReadOnly() for the NativeList to pass to func2() that makes sure it is used as a read only.

```
private void func1()
{
    var newList = new NativeList<int>(1024, Allocator.Temp);
    // write to newList
    func2(newList.AsReadOnly());
}

//need the read function to be burstable
[BurstCompile]
private static void func2(NativeArray<int>.ReadOnly newList)
{
    // do read operations on the newList
}
```